# how retrieve the profile picture of instagram user who posted a comment using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

i'm using this query to get comments of post in Bussines account Instagram

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{post-id}/comments?fields=from,text,timestamp,media,user,username,id
```

and i need to get the user porfile image

i tried this endpoints but they seems doesn't work anymore
[https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1)
https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/USER_ID/info/

Comment: I am not sure if you can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/ with this type of user, but give it a try.